# Make python chromedriver script run faster (change send_keys *too slow*)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, wait

Hello I have built a program script that goes onto a website and selects a size and auto checks out an Item for me it works very well but I have 2 concerns

1.I want to have this script run faster before the script ran pretty fast (so fast that it basically added to cart and went to the checkout page before the Item could even load into the cart (which resulted in errors) and so I added there script to my code 
`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`  and this one which I mainly used to wait until the item loaded into the cart and all the "add to cart" buttons showed up
`wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'commit')))`
but I want this script to run faster I tried changing the
`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` into something like
`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)` and 
`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)` but I see no difference is there anything I can do to make the script run faster?(it doesnt have to do with the wait= thing Ill take any thing I can get to even shave off milaseconds.

2. I am currently using the send_keys option for autofill which is PAINFULLY SLOW is there anything I can use that will fill all the stuff instanstly alltogether? ik there are some "JAVA-scripts simular to this that can do it but im not sure how to right java script or more importantly how to even combine them

Can anyone help me out I just want my selenium python chromedriver script to run as fast as possible.

Thank you.

(for my script im using select for the size and just .click()   and a couple of if statements which depends on how many items they want to cart   and lots of def fweuf

fweuf()   (i forget what those are called lol) )

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending values with JS you can do this:

```
js= "document.getElementById('YOURELEMENT').value = '" + str(YOURVALUE) + "';"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that works thank you but... it fills in the complete word instantly but it still does it in order... Is there anyway that I can make it fill in all the text boxes at once??? @Valter Hudovernik

Comment: Send multiple commands at once and it should work. If you cant get it working I will write an example when I get to a computer

Comment: ok awsome thanks!! how would I send multiple commands at once exactly??  @Valter Hudovernik

Comment: concatenate to the js string for example `js+="NEW COMMAND"` before you call `execute_scripts`

Comment: It WORKED!! Thank you so much @Valter Hudovernik

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj glad I could help